# Moving Files to an extrenal Hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

When I turned on my computer, the gui would not let me login. I can login in through the command window, though. After some cursory looking around (checking permissions, moving all the files to a new directory and changing administrator accounts by deleting the old one and creating a new one), I have decided on moving all my files to an external hard drive and re-installing ubuntu.

So I plugged in my external hard drive and it showed up under /dev/sdb

I ran

> fdisk /dev/sdb

and created a new primary partition in 3 and used the default positions for the rest.

I than ran

> mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb

and realized I just created a filesystem on the entire hard drive. I reran the command as

> mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb3

and had no errors.

Despite doing all of this, I get back an error saying that /dev/sdb and /dev/sdb3 are not files or directories when I run

> ls /dev/sdb

and

> ls /dev/sdb3

, respectively.

What are the steps I will have to take before I can move my files from my computer into this new partitioned external hard drive, based on what I have done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tot mount the disk first, you can not list a device.To do so you need to type:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sdb3
```

(Or a different location)

Then:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/sdb3
```

Now you will able to access the drive:

```
ls /mnt/sdb3
```